# Mysql After insert trigger fails

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying a mysql trigger. It is my first time

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `mega_insert`;
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER mega_insert AFTER INSERT ON purchase_master
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mega_score_genre (test_id,user_id,package_id)
    SELECT p.test_id
    ,:NEW.user_id
    ,:NEW.package_id
    FROM package_master p
    ON p.package_id = :NEW.package_id;       
  END;
|

delimiter ;
```

It is not working `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':NEW.user_id`.

I tried different things but i could not get it working. If anyone can help me getting this work, I will be helpful.

In this I am trying to populate * mega_score_genre* table whenever something inserted into *purchase_master* table & get test_id filed from package_master table where package_master.package_id = purchase_master.package_id

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive.

`NEW`, not `:NEW`.

Out of curiosity, from what example or reference did you get the idea that you should spell it `:NEW`?

Second problem: You have only one table in your SELECT. You're not doing a JOIN so you can't have an ON clause. Read about the syntax of SELECT here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

The example should use WHERE instead of ON if it wants to select some rows based on a condition.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited that answer to fix it, so no one else gets the wrong example.

Comment: NEW is also not working 'p.package_id = NEW.package_id;

Comment: It should be WHERE instead of ON. Also, put the entire SELECT block in braces just to be safe. @raju